# Difference between two time stored as text

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has check out and check in times but these times are in text format. I want the difference between these two times.

Example:

```
Check out Check in
1015      1331
0642      0911
1002      1242
1434      1658
1821      2058
2221      0051
```

Getting error when i run this query:

> ORA-02000: missing ) keyword
>   02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

Comment: How far have you got with a solution? What output do you want? Do you know that the times are always on the same day, or at least less than 24 hours (as the last example goes past midnight)?

Comment: if you see 3rd row 1002 1242 = (output) 2:44 .. times not always on the same day it will goes midnight .. e.g Checkin  24/08/2016 22:21:00 -- check out 25/08/2016 00:51:00

Comment: Surely row three should be 2:40 then, not 2:44? And are you actually recording those dates (in another column; if so is it also text or a proper date?) or is that just an example?

Comment: Yes Application recording those dates in another columns as Varchar2

Comment: Well, that's a bad data model - why not use a proper data column which includes the time? But anyway, you can include the date string when converting the time, rather than defaulting to the first of the month; you then don't assume it can only span one day, though if it can then you need to decide if you show the number of days or show the hours value as greater than 24.

Comment: I have tweaked the formatting of your question to improve readability. However, it would be useful if you could [edit] your question further to improve it; for example, could you show the expected output you are hoping to get for each pair of times, and also show the query you are using which gets the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to a time on a nominal date using `to_date()`; if you don't provide a date part then it defaults to the first day of the current month; using a CTE (subquery factoring) to create a dummy table `t` with your sample data:

```
with t (check_out, check_in) as (
  select '1015', '1331' from dual
  union all select '0642', '0911' from dual
  union all select '1002', '1242' from dual
  union all select '1434', '1658' from dual
  union all select '1821', '2058' from dual
  union all select '2221', '0051' from dual
)
select check_out, check_in,
  to_char(to_date(check_out, 'HH24MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as d1,
  to_char(to_date(check_in, 'HH24MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as d2
from t;

CHEC CHEC D1                  D2                
---- ---- ------------------- -------------------
1015 1331 2016-08-01 10:15:00 2016-08-01 13:31:00
0642 0911 2016-08-01 06:42:00 2016-08-01 09:11:00
1002 1242 2016-08-01 10:02:00 2016-08-01 12:42:00
1434 1658 2016-08-01 14:34:00 2016-08-01 16:58:00
1821 2058 2016-08-01 18:21:00 2016-08-01 20:58:00
2221 0051 2016-08-01 22:21:00 2016-08-01 00:51:00
```

You can then subtract one of those dates from the other. But as your times go over midnight and therefore span two days, you need to adjust the check in time by a day if the time it represents is earlier than the check out time - which is the case in your last example. You can figure that out with a case expression, even comparing as strings if they are always four characters (zero-padded). So you can do:

```
select check_out, check_in,
  to_char(to_date(check_out, 'HH24MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as d1,
  to_char(to_date(check_in, 'HH24MI') + case when check_in < check_out then 1 else 0 end,
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as d2
from t;

CHEC CHEC D1                  D2                
---- ---- ------------------- -------------------
1015 1331 2016-08-01 10:15:00 2016-08-01 13:31:00
0642 0911 2016-08-01 06:42:00 2016-08-01 09:11:00
1002 1242 2016-08-01 10:02:00 2016-08-01 12:42:00
1434 1658 2016-08-01 14:34:00 2016-08-01 16:58:00
1821 2058 2016-08-01 18:21:00 2016-08-01 20:58:00
2221 0051 2016-08-01 22:21:00 2016-08-02 00:51:00
```

Notice the check in time on the last row is now the following day.

And then subtract, which gives you a fraction of a day as the difference:

```
select check_out, check_in,
  to_date(check_in, 'HH24MI')
    + case when check_in < check_out then 1 else 0 end -- adjust if check_in is next day
    - to_date(check_out, 'HH24MI') as diff
from t;

CHEC CHEC       DIFF
---- ---- ----------
1015 1331    0.13611
0642 0911    0.10347
1002 1242    0.11111
1434 1658    0.10000
1821 2058    0.10903
2221 0051    0.10417
```

If you add that fraction to another nominal date, with its time as midnight, then you get a date with the time part matching the difference between the check out and check in times. You can then format that however you want:

```
with t (check_out, check_in) as (
  select '1015', '1331' from dual
  union all select '0642', '0911' from dual
  union all select '1002', '1242' from dual
  union all select '1434', '1658' from dual
  union all select '1821', '2058' from dual
  union all select '2221', '0051' from dual
)
select check_out, check_in, to_char(trunc(sysdate) + diff, 'HH24:MI') as diff
from (
  select check_out, check_in,
    to_date(check_in, 'HH24MI')
      + case when check_in < check_out then 1 else 0 end -- adjust if check_in is next day
      - to_date(check_out, 'HH24MI') as diff
  from t
);

CHEC CHEC DIFF
---- ---- -----
1015 1331 03:16
0642 0911 02:29
1002 1242 02:40
1434 1658 02:24
1821 2058 02:37
2221 0051 02:30
```

Your real query will not have the CTE, but will select directly from your real table:

```
select OUTUDT, INUDT, to_char(trunc(sysdate) + diff, 'HH24:MI') as diff
from (
  select OUTUDT, INUDT,
    to_date(OUTUDT, 'HH24MI') + case when INUDT < OUTUDT then 1 else 0 end
    - to_date(INUDT, 'HH24MI') as diff 
  from your_real_table
)
```

Of course, this assumes the period between check out and check in is never more than 24 hours. As you aren't recording the date properly you have no way to know if any span is actually longer than that.

---

If you want to use your 'date' column (also stored as text) then you can concatenate that with the time and convert to an actual date:

```
with t (check_out_date, check_out_time, check_in_date, check_in_time) as (
  select '24/08/2016', '1015', '24/08/2016', '1331' from dual
  union all select '23/08/2016', '0642', '23/08/2016', '0911' from dual
  union all select '23/08/2016', '1002', '23/08/2016', '1242' from dual
  union all select '23/08/2016', '1434', '23/08/2016', '1658' from dual
  union all select '24/08/2016', '1821', '24/08/2016', '2058' from dual
  union all select '24/08/2016', '2221', '25/08/2016', '0051' from dual
)
select check_out_date, check_out_time, check_in_date, check_in_time,
  to_char(trunc(sysdate) + diff, 'HH24:MI') as diff
from (
  select check_out_date, check_out_time, check_in_date, check_in_time,
    to_date(check_in_date || check_in_time, 'DD/MM/YYYYHH24MI')
      - to_date(check_out_date || check_out_time, 'DD/MM/YYYYHH24MI') as diff
  from t
);

CHECK_OUT_ CHEC CHECK_IN_D CHEC DIFF
---------- ---- ---------- ---- -----
24/08/2016 1015 24/08/2016 1331 03:16
23/08/2016 0642 23/08/2016 0911 02:29
23/08/2016 1002 23/08/2016 1242 02:40
23/08/2016 1434 23/08/2016 1658 02:24
24/08/2016 1821 24/08/2016 2058 02:37
24/08/2016 2221 25/08/2016 0051 02:30
```

That concatenation and conversion wouldn't be necessary if you were storing dates properly - it is not a good idea to store things as strings when there are specific data types available.

If the period can span more than a day you'll need to change how you display the difference.

Comment: im getting error .. when i use this query                                             with t (OUTUDT,INUDT) as (
  select OUTUDT,INUDT from dual
)
select OUTUDT,INUDT, to_char(trunc(sysdate) + diff, 'HH24:MI') as diff
from (
  select OUTUDT,INUDT,
    to_date(OUTUDT, 'HH24MI')
      + case when INUDT < OUTUDT then 1 else 0 end -- adjust if check_in is next day
      - to_date(INUDT, 'HH24MI') as diff
  from t
);                                                                                          ORA-00904: "INUDT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifie

Comment: The `t` CTE is creating dummy data. Query your real table instead - `select outudt, ... as diff from your_real_table`. INUDT and OUTUDT are the columns that only hold the time, not any date part, right?

Comment: I have date columns can we do subtract with date column and this timing column

Comment: @FaisalKhan - by converting the date and time strings to an actual date; I've added an example. You should really revisit your data model though and see if you can change it to use actual date columns. And the adding-to-sysdate trick isn't going to work if the period spans more than a day, but you'll need to decide what you want to do and see if that can happen.

Comment: Alex Poole i used your last query and its worked but i add some more tables with this query and im getting error (ORA-02000: missing ) keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword")   i updated my query in main Question

Comment: @FaisalKhan - [that is a new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/266304). But your CTE construct is wrong; remove the `RM_MVTCTRL.` prefixes from the column names - `with t (ORIGIN, EMPLOYEEPOSITION, IDENTIFIER, ...) as ...`. You also aren't including those columns in the select list, so you've basically just misconstructed the CTE. I don't think you actually need or want the CTE at all.

Comment: Seems your need to work on time. I guess your understanding about time in Hours is weak. According to you if a a person checkout at 1015 and checkin at 1331 the time difference is only 03:16 hrs. That's pretty silly. I hope you understand the fact only a person who checkin can only checkout.

Comment: @Raj_Te - check in is *after* check out, so yes, 10:15 to 13:31 is three hours 16 minutes. How long do you think that gap is? Only one of the examples in the question goes over midnight. (It appears to be flight departure and arrival times in the real query but it isn't clear). The OP has said this is correct though.

Comment: Did you check the question. What's checkin time mentioned over there..Read once again and mention to me what you understood as checkin   time and checkout time in question. I guess you didnot even read the question properly. Also your solution is not correct. it didnot serve the purpose. You just wrote your theory which is useless and that's also wrong. You seriously deserve a downvote here.

Comment: @Raj_Te - yes, I'm happy I understand it. Also see OP's comment, "3rd row 1002 1242 = (output) 2:44" - which should be 2:40 really, but either way isn't 21:20 which is what is would be is check out was after check in. You're assuming it's something like hotel system where out would be after in; but that does not seem to be the case. As I said, they look like flight departure/arrival times. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Also see earlier comment on this answer from the OP - "i used your last query and its worked". The OP seems to think it's correct and serves the purpose. You're free to have your own opinion of course, and your downvotes are yours to use however you want.

Comment: Well you are also now assuming here its a flight departure case like i assumed it a hotel case. However, i have never seen any airport showing flight departure as checkout and flight arrival as checkin. And when you had not clarity on the case how can you downvote anyone and say the answer is not making sense.

Comment: I'm not assuming they are flights (though the OP's edit with real column names suggests that), I am just assuming check in is after check out - which isn't really an assumption as that is what the OP said. I think that is clear.

Comment: And even if that assumption turns out to be wrong, you just need to swap the column names over; the mechanism works either way.